# How can you solve a couple system of quadratic differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose there is a differential equation in the form of

$$\mathbf y'(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2+y_1^2\\ \end{bmatrix}.$$
Not only is it non-linear, but it is coupled. Is there a general method of solving systems in this form? Can I just take the exponential of it as I would with a linear system? Or is there a method of substitution such as $y_3=y_2^2$?

Comment: Well, in this case, you have $y_1' = y_1$, which you can use to find $y_1$ and then use that in the second equation to find $y_2$.

Comment: Is $\bf{y} = \begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 0):

$y_1'(t)=y_1(t)$ gives $y_1(t)=ce^{t}$ and $y_2'(t)=y_2(t)+y_1^{2}(t)=y_2(t)+c^{2}e^{2t}$ is a first order linear equation. Now $\frac d {dt} (e^{-t}y_2(t))'=e^{-t}(y_2'(t)-y_2(t))=c^{2}e^{t}$. Integrate both sides to find $y_2(t)$.

Comment: Is the case for $y_2'(t)$ considered separable? $t$ isn't constant, I don't see how this is linear unless $t$ can be held constant as $y$ is integrated.

Comment: @VaneVoe See my revised answer. I have used a standard technique of multiplying by the  'integrating factor' $e^{-t}$.

Comment: So, there's no standard method like taking the exponential of a matrix? You just have to hope you get lucky with an integrating factor?

Comment: @VaneVoe Equations of the type $y'(t)=f(t)y(t)+g(t)$ where $f$ and $g$ are given functions can always be solved using integrating factors.